# How to change log level for MongoDB logs?

Tags: mongodb, log-level

Is there any way to change the default log level for MongoDB ?

There're too many insertion/update entries in the log file, causing it grow way too big.

**command used to start mongo:**

```
./bin/mongod --fork --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 --dbpath /data/db/ --logpath /data/log/mongodb/mongod.log --logappend --quiet --logRotate reopen
```

**the log file is filled with:**

```
2018-08-31T11:30:46.831+0800 I COMMAND  [conn564] command eques.$cmd command: insert
```

I just need error or more severe level entries.

Answer (score 4):

Check the verbosity levels first

```
db.getLogComponents()
```

Note : All components not specified explicitly in the configuration have a verbosity level of -1, indicating that they inherit the verbosity level of their parent, if they have one, or the global verbosity level (systemLog.verbosity) if they do not.

Use the `db.setLogLevel(<level>, <component>)` method to update a single component log level.

For a component, you can specify verbosity level of `0 to 5`, or you can specify `-1` to inherit the verbosity of the parent.

For example, the following sets the `systemLog.component.query.verbosity` to its parent verbosity (i.e. default verbosity):

```
db.setLogLevel(-1, "query")
```

More info : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/

Comment: This function not available in 2.6 version..how to check  any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The verbosity can be set to 0 overall and every individual component inherits the parent verbosity setting (of 0). That is as low as the verbosity setting goes. To further reduce the logging you can set **systemLog.quiet** but that is not recommended for production systems because it can make tracking down issues too difficult and it may not address the root cause in any case.

More - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's sad, I have enabled quite flag, but nothing changed.